# Current Field Value into a VBA String Programmatically

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to take the current value of a field from the record displayed on an open Access form and put the text in that field into a VBA string programmatically. This seems so simple but I have not yet been to find any guidance from either an aftermarket Access 2013 text I purchased or the Internet. I have tried everything I can think of with no success whatsoever so I posted a question on stackoverflow.com and received the following suggested solution:

```
        Dim strYourString as String
    strYourString = Forms![Your Form Name].[Field Name].Value
```

When this is run I get:
    Runtime error ‘438’
    Object doesn’t support this property or method

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a bang symbol in front of the field name, instead of a period.

```
strYourString = Forms![Your Form Name]![Field Name].Value
                                      ^---------------------Bang symbol here
```

This is supported by the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195841%28v=office.15%29.aspx) on MSDN.  Note the implicit form:

```
Forms!OrderForm!NewData
```

where NewData is the *name of a control.*  Or you can use an explicit reference:

```
Forms!OrderForm.Controls!NewData
```

If you want to refer to a field in the underlying recordset of the form instead, use:

```
Forms!MyForm.Recordset.Fields("MyFieldName")
```